# Plot multiple geometric brownian motions

Tags: r, data-visualization

I created various simulations of geometric Brownian motions in R using the following codes:

```
m <- 10
n <- 1000
mu <- 0.15
sigma <- 0.3
s0 <- 10
T1 <- 5
set.seed(70967993)
MotiBr <- matrix(rnorm(m*n, 0, sqrt(T1/n)), n, m)
MotiBr <- apply(MotiBr, 2, diffinv)
temp <- (0:n)/n*T1
MotiBr <- (mu - sigma^2/2)*temp + sigma*MotiBr
MotiBr <- t(s0*exp(MotiBr))
```

Now I want to plot the results in a graph like this:

[image]

Note that it's not a GBM, I posted just to expose the result that I want to get. Can someone post here the code to build a plot like that using my simulations in `MotiBr`?

PS: I give to T1 the value 5, but the period that I mean is [0,5], is it right to code it just with `T1 <- 5`?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you may be looking for a `matplot` function e.g.

```
matplot(temp, t(MotiBr), type = "l", col = "black")
```

produces the following plot

[image]

Comment: This works perfectly and it is also simple, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to create a plot for your data.

First, transform the matrix into a data frame in the long format.

```
dat <- data.frame(val = as.vector(MotiBr),
                  idx = seq(nrow(MotiBr)),
                  time = rep(seq(ncol(MotiBr)), each = nrow(MotiBr)))
```

One way to plot the data is the `ggplot2` package.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x = time, y = val, group = idx)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]